# How to scrape just four numeric values from a HTML web page's table on Java for Android?

Tags: java, android, html, parsing

Here's my current code:

```
 private static String fetch(String url) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
String userAgent1 = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36 OPR/56.0.3051.43";
try {
    Document doc1 = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(userAgent1).get();
    Elements divTags = doc1.getElementsByTag("div");
    String re = "^<div class=\\\"Ta\\(c\\) Py\\(6px\\) Bxz\\(bb\\) BdB Bdc\\(\\$seperatorColor\\) Miw\\(120px\\) Miw\\(100px\\)\\-\\-pnclg D\\(tbc\\)\\\" data-test=\\\"fin-col\\\"><span>.*</span></div>$";
    
    for (Element div : divTags) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(re, Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(div.html());

        if (matcher.find()) {
            String data = matcher.group(1);
            Log.d("Matched: ", data);
        }
        else {
            Log.d("Nothing Matched: ", "");
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("err-new", "err", e);
}
return "";
```

}

This function takes a URL as input, in our case: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL&guccounter=2 and extracts all the div tags using JSOUP.

And then, I need to extract these values using Pattern matching. But, in my code above, all I get is that "Nothing matched: ".

Here's the web page from which I am interested in getting the four numeric values corresponding to the first four yearly columns, corresponding to the row named `EBIT`. (Stands for Earnings Before Interest and Taxes)

**Link**: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL&guccounter=2

**Input**:
Looking to get values 122,034,000, 111,852,000, 69,964,000, 69,313,000 on the `EBIT` row for columns 9/30/2022, 9/30/2021, 9/30/2020, 9/30/2019.

On `Inspect`, these values are under the following `<div>` tags.

EBIT 1: `<div class="Ta(c) Py(6px) Bxz(bb) BdB Bdc($seperatorColor) Miw(120px) Miw(100px)--pnclg D(tbc)" data-test="fin-col"><span>122,034,000</span></div>`

EBIT 2: `<div class="Ta(c) Py(6px) Bxz(bb) BdB Bdc($seperatorColor) Miw(120px) Miw(100px)--pnclg Bgc($lv1BgColor) fi-row:h_Bgc($hoverBgColor) D(tbc)" data-test="fin-col"><span>111,852,000</span></div>`

EBIT 3: `<div class="Ta(c) Py(6px) Bxz(bb) BdB Bdc($seperatorColor) Miw(120px) Miw(100px)--pnclg D(tbc)" data-test="fin-col"><span>69,964,000</span></div>`

EBIT 4: `<div class="Ta(c) Py(6px) Bxz(bb) BdB Bdc($seperatorColor) Miw(120px) Miw(100px)--pnclg Bgc($lv1BgColor) fi-row:h_Bgc($hoverBgColor) D(tbc)" data-test="fin-col"><span>69,313,000</span></div>`

And the same thing for the 4 columns under the `Quarterly` tab on the same web page. Looking to get values 25,484,000, 23,785,000, 30,830,000, 41,935,000 on the `EBIT` row for columns 9/30/2022, 6/30/2022, 3/31/2022, 12/31/2021.

EBIT 1: `<div class="Ta(c) Py(6px) Bxz(bb) BdB Bdc($seperatorColor) Miw(120px) Miw(100px)--pnclg D(tbc)" data-test="fin-col"><span>25,484,000</span></div>`

EBIT 2: `<div class="Ta(c) Py(6px) Bxz(bb) BdB Bdc($seperatorColor) Miw(120px) Miw(100px)--pnclg Bgc($lv1BgColor) fi-row:h_Bgc($hoverBgColor) D(tbc)" data-test="fin-col"><span>23,785,000</span></div>`

EBIT 3: `<div class="Ta(c) Py(6px) Bxz(bb) BdB Bdc($seperatorColor) Miw(120px) Miw(100px)--pnclg D(tbc)" data-test="fin-col"><span>30,830,000</span></div>`

EBIT 4: `<div class="Ta(c) Py(6px) Bxz(bb) BdB Bdc($seperatorColor) Miw(120px) Miw(100px)--pnclg Bgc($lv1BgColor) fi-row:h_Bgc($hoverBgColor) D(tbc)" data-test="fin-col"><span>41,935,000</span></div>`

**Output**:
dates = {9/30/2022, 9/30/2021, 9/30/2020, 9/30/2019}

datesQ = {9/30/2022, 6/30/2022, 3/31/2022, 12/31/2021}

EBIT = {122,034,000, 111,852,000, 69,964,000, 69,313,000}

EBITQ = {25,484,000, 23,785,000, 30,830,000, 41,935,000}

Where `Q` stands for Quarterly.

OR, it could be two hashmaps with
yearlyHash = {date1: value1, date2: value2, date3: value3 and date4: value4}
quarterlyHash = {date1: value1, date2: value2, date3: value3 and date4: value4}

My existing code is broken. Basically, I've used JSoup to get all the javascript related tags and used a pattern matcher to get the String values I wanted. However, the page I'm parsing now seems to look like some values in that tag are encrypted strings that can't be parsed anymore.

My use case is not that complex as you can imagine. I just need the dates and the 4 values corresponding to that one row. Even if it's a non-standard, non-optimized solution, I am fine with that.

Thank you.

Comment: I never used the data of this API by myself, but usually in every system in this world, the data that you see, is being exposed as an Rest API. Here you can consume the data on a standard way by parsing the JSON, instead of extracting some weird HTML out of the page.

https://cryptocointracker.com/yahoo-finance/yahoo-finance-api

Comment: For example this one would give you the financial data from AAPL which contains the EBIT.


https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v11/finance/quoteSummary/aapl?&modules=financialData

Comment: I only see `EBITDA` there and that too for one year. 
I was looking for four years' data along with `EBIT` data for those four years. Are you sure you sent me the right link?

Comment: I just sent you an example / hint - as I mentioned, I never worked with the API by myself, so I am not quite sure, if the API has everything you want, so its your job to look up if it has any endpoints that give you exact the same data, or if you need to calculate it by yourself by taking some other data from the API. Usually scrapping HTML is not necessary, if the API might expose the data in a JSON Format. But if it doesn't - sure HTML Scrapping is a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use regular expression to match the div tags

Please change your regular expression to match the span element and extract the text inside it.

ex:

```
Elements spans = doc1.select("div.Ta(c) span");
for (Element span : spans) {
    String data = span.text();
    Log.d("Matched: ", data);
}
```

Also you might use Jsoup's elements class & filter method to filter the divs to extract the span elements.

```
Elements divs = doc1.select("div[class*=Ta\\(c\\)]");
Elements spanElements = divs.filter(element -> element.select("span").size()>0);
for (Element span : spanElements) {
    String data = span.text();
    Log.d("Matched: ", data);
}
```

Using Css selectors will be also possible.

Comment: Sorry, where in my function (in the question) should I put this? I have a for loop that get div tags...

Comment: Also, it just throws an error: "org.jsoup.select.Selector$SelectorParseException: Could not parse query 'div.Ta(c) span': unexpected token at '(c) span'"

Comment: You can place the `beautifulsoup.select_one()` method within the for loop, after the `divs=soup.find_all("div", clas_="class-name")` line.

Comment: like this: 
for div in divs: 
 div_class = beautifulsoup.select_one(div, "div.class-name")

Answer (score 0):

Annoyingly the annual data is on the page as loaded and the quarterly data is loaded with a AJAX call triggered by clicking on the "Quarterly" button. Anyway, the following code will do the job:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class App {
    private static final String PAGE_URL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL&guccounter=2";
    private static final String DATA_URL = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/ws/fundamentals-timeseries/v1/finance/timeseries/AAPL?lang=en-US&region=US&symbol=AAPL&padTimeSeries=true&type=quarterlyEBIT&merge=false&period1=493590046&period2=1674660504&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com";

    private static final String REGEX_YAHOO_PAGE_EBIT = "^.*ttm</span>.*?<span>(.*?)</span>.*?<span>(.*?)</span>.*?<span>(.*?)</span>.*?<span>(.*?)</span>.*?EBIT</span></div><div.*?<span>(.*?)</span>.*?<span>(.*?)</span>.*?<span>(.*?)</span>.*?<span>(.*?)</span>.*?<span>(.*?)</span>.*$";
    private static final Pattern PATTERN_YAHOO_PAGE_REGEX = Pattern.compile(REGEX_YAHOO_PAGE_EBIT, Pattern.DOTALL);

    private static final Gson GSON = new Gson();

    private static final NumberFormat NUMBER_FORMAT = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("en", "US"));

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String pageContent = fetch(PAGE_URL);
        Matcher m = PATTERN_YAHOO_PAGE_REGEX.matcher(pageContent);
        if (m.matches()) {
            System.out.println("Annual values");

            System.out.println(m.group(1) + ": " + m.group(6));
            System.out.println(m.group(2) + ": " + m.group(7));
            System.out.println(m.group(3) + ": " + m.group(8));
            System.out.println(m.group(4) + ": " + m.group(9));
        }

        // the quarterly data is not on the page. it is rendered dynamically from this
        // AJAX call
        String quarterlyData = fetch(DATA_URL);
        System.out.println("Quarterly values");
        Map map = GSON.fromJson(quarterlyData, Map.class);
        List<Map> result = (List<Map>) ((Map) map.get("timeseries")).get("result");
        for (Map entry : result) {
            Map meta = (Map) entry.get("meta");
            if (((List<String>) meta.get("type")).get(0).equals("quarterlyEBIT")) {
                List<Map<String, Object>> quarterlyEBIT = (List) entry.get("quarterlyEBIT");
                for (Map<String, Object> cell : quarterlyEBIT) {
                    System.out.print(cell.get("asOfDate") + ": ");
                    String fullNumberString = NUMBER_FORMAT
                            .format(((Map<String, Double>) cell.get("reportedValue")).get("raw"));
                    System.out.println(fullNumberString.substring(0, fullNumberString.length() - 4));

                }

            }
        }

    }

    private static String fetch(String url) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        URL pageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection pageConnection = (HttpURLConnection) pageUrl.openConnection();
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(pageConnection.getInputStream());
            int bufferSize = 1024;
            char[] buffer = new char[bufferSize];
            StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
            Reader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
            for (int numRead; (numRead = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0;) {
                out.append(buffer, 0, numRead);
            }
            return out.toString();
        } finally {
            pageConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Annual values
9/30/2022: 122,034,000
9/30/2021: 111,852,000
9/30/2020: 69,964,000
9/30/2019: 69,313,000
Quarterly values
2021-12-31: 41,935,000
2022-03-31: 30,830,000
2022-06-30: 23,785,000
2022-09-30: 25,484,000
```

If you prefer Apache HttpClient (v4 here) then fetch() can be coded as follows:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

    private static String fetch(String url) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
        try {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            return EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I am a total beginner. So, is there a way you can help rewrite this to use Java for Android, esp. the `fetch` method? 

The `fetch` method in your code doesn't directly translate to Android. I'd like to know what the output of the `out.toString()` string looks like that's used for parsing.

Comment: I specially wrote it to work with Android. Which classes do you not have access to? java.net? java.util.regex? com.google.gson.Gson?

Comment: fetch() returns the body of the HTTP GET just like a call from the browser, eg  DATA_URL returns {"timeseries":{"result":[{"meta":{"symbol":["AAPL"],"type":["quarterlyEBIT"]},"timestamp":[1640908800,1648684800,1656547200,1664496000],"quarterlyEBIT":[{"dataId":20189,"asOfDate":"2021-12-31","periodType":"3M","currencyCode":"USD","reportedValue":{"raw":4.1935E10,"fmt":"41.94B"}},{"dataId":20189,"asOfDate":"2022-03-31","periodType":"3M","currencyCode":"USD","reportedValue":{"raw":3.083E10,"fmt":"30.83B"}},{"dataId":20189,"asOfDate":"2022-06-30","periodType":"3M","currencyCode":"USD",… TRUNCATED

Comment: I can rewrite fetch() to use Apache Http Client but that is very old school. See https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/android.html

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? 1.8^ ?

Comment: I have added an implementation of fetch() with Apache HttpClient (v4)

Comment: Yes, it's Java 1.8, but I don't understand your fetch() method at all. What's the best way to get the buffered HTTP Get response on Java for Android such that I can test out your regex pattern matcher works?

Comment: Did you try the Apache HttpClient implementation of fetch() that I added to the answer?

Comment: Yes, I get the W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

on the line,  String quarterlyData = fetch(DATA_URL);
                    Map map = GSON.fromJson(quarterlyData, Map.class);

Basically, output of fetch is null. No response from Annual values section either.

Comment: This is the code I am using now for the fetch function - still nothing - https://codeshare.io/LwVKPK

Please check it out and let me know what mistake I am making.

Comment: Your fetch() method is essentially the same as my first variant and pretty much the standard approach. Something is wrong with your setup.

Comment: If I tried your latest Apache method, I get the Java.lang.NoSuchFieldError on the line `CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();`. 

Sorry, what do you mean by "Something is wrong with your setup"? How can I troubleshoot? Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you are using apache http client 5. Change your org.apache.http imports to the following and throw the new ParseException: import org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClients;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.ParseException;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.io.entity.EntityUtils;

Comment: I would not know where to start getting your java environment working with http calls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251416/discussion-between-zac1-and-john-williams).

Comment: I think it’s time to accept my answer. Then you need to work out why you can’t make any http request from your setup, maybe try another client, eg okhttp

Comment: Is there any chance you can maybe share a running environment for this program through an online Java environment?

Comment: Yes, which do you suggest? It’s late here so I will be tomorrow, ie about 07:30 UTC

Comment: Can you please take one peek at this please (https://codeshare.io/WdVn4b)? This JSOUP returns the whole webpage source. However, the pattern matcher doesn't work on this. That's why I was wondering how best to return the data to your pattern matcher.

Comment: I may be wrong but I suspect that an online environment will not allow outgoing http calls.

Comment: I updated the code above (codeshare.io/WdVn4b) with the result I am getting on the `result` variable. Can you please take a peek and let me know if that's the right input needed for your pattern matcher?

Comment: Don’t return String.valueOf(result), just result.
That result, ie html page is the right format for the first (regex) pattern matches.

Comment: Thanks. I've made sure the long HTML gets passed as input to the matcher. But the program just stops executing (no error output) because I suspect the HTML page is too long for the matcher. I see nothing in the log despite catching errors and having if, else statements based on if the pattern is matched or not (but no output meaning the code is just stuck).

Comment: May I ask how you came up with your Regex string? That doesn't seem to be matching anything.

Why can't I just use a string like this, `String re = "Ta(c) Py(6px) Bxz(bb) BdB Bdc($seperatorColor) Miw(120px) Miw(100px)--pnclg Bgc($lv1BgColor) fi-row:h_Bgc($hoverBgColor) D(tbc)";` and match the string contents after every `div` tag extracted via a JSOUP Element? Is that a flawed method?

Comment: Regex is fine. Yours isn't a regex. Test my regex with the correct payload (https://codeshare.io/N3Vnjm your codeshare payload has a bunch of " D/Doc1::" in it) on https://regex101.com. Options Java 8 and regex options gm (should be default). Anyway, in the absence of a bounty I'm out.